# Python access parent object instances

Tags: python, pygame, python-import

I'm currently trying to write a multiple-file Python (2.6.5) game using PyGame.  The problem is that one of the files, "pyconsole.py", needs to be able to call methods on instances of other objects imported by the primary file, "main.py".  The problem is that I have a list in the main file to hold instances of all of the game objects (player's ship, enemy ships, stations, etc.), yet I can't seem to be able to call methods from that list within "pyconsole.py" despite the fact that I'm doing a `from pyconsole import *` in "main.py" before the main loop starts.  Is this simply not possible, and should I instead use M4 to combine every file into 1 single file and then bytecode-compile and test/distribute that?

Example:

```
bash$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import math, distancefrom00
foo = 5

class BarClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = 10
    def get(self):
        print "The BAZ is ", self.baz
    def switch(self)
        self.baz = 15
        self.get()

bar = BarClass()

def main():
    bar.switch()
    print distancefrom00.calculate([2, 4])

if __name__ == '__main__': main()

bash$ cat distancefrom00.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import math
import test

def calculate(otherpoint):
    return str(math.hypot(otherpoint[0], otherpoint[1]))+" (foo = "+str(test.foo)+"; "+test.bar.get()+")"

bash$ python test.py
The BAZ is  15
The BAZ is  10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "test.py", line 22, in main
    print distancefrom00.calculate([2, 4])
  File "/home/archie/Development/Python/Import Test/distancefrom00.py", line 8, in calculate
    return str(math.hypot(otherpoint[0], otherpoint[1]))+" (foo = "+str(test.foo)+"; "+test.bar.get()+")"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

If my somewhat limited understanding of Python names, classes, and all that stuff is correct here, the NoneType means that the name `test.bar.get()` - and thus, `test.bar` - is not assigned to anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to be able to call methods"? Please include some sample code and provide the exception you get.

Comment: Ah - and just in case. Please do not involve M4 in any build script for your own safety. Python modules work correctly, you've got a bug somewhere. M4 is evil.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about M4 (besides forgetting to use the `-P` flag so it doesn't clobber existing text) is evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that one of the files,
>   "pyconsole.py", needs to be able to
>   call methods on instances of other
>   objects imported by the primary file,
>   "main.py".

This just sounds like the dependencies are wrong. Generally nothing should be calling 'backwards' up to the main file. That main.py should be the glue that holds everything else together, and nothing should depend on it. Technically the dependencies should form a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). As soon as you find a cycle in your dependency graph, move out the common aspects into a new file to break the cycle.

So, move the things in 'main.py' that are used by 'pyconsole.py' out into a new file. Then have 'main.py' and 'pyconsole.py' import that new file.

Comment: OK, if I'm understanding you correctly, that means that every instance of the resources (the sound/sprite objects, the list of game objects, etc.) needs to be put in a separate file, then imported by `main.py`, `pyconsole.py`, and everything else that deals with those objects?  My question here is: will doing so actually cause each separate file to be working on the same "copy" of the namespace of each other file that is `import`ed, or will I end up making endless copies of every namespace, with each one being influenced by only one other file (which is not the behavior of choice, obviously)?

Comment: It's not really about instances of resources, but about code dependency. The resources can be instantiated wherever you like. But if you have an object that exists in one file and is used in many others, that sounds like a global variable and is almost always a bad idea. As for your namespace question, within one program, each module (ie. a file you import) exists once and once only. If two different files access pyconsole.something then that name refers to the same object in both cases.

Comment: Ah, that's what I didn't understand. I was unsure of whether Python internally used a scheme similar to how you protect C[++] header files from being `#include` -ed more than once using constants. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: To be pedantic, in C++ they're not actually constants, just preprocessor definitions. Python performs a similar check automatically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, note that when you run test.py as a script it is module `__main__`. When you import `test.py` from `distancefrom00.py` that creates a new `test` module. `bar` in the main script and `test.bar` accessible from `distancefrom00.py` are completely unrelated. They aren't even the same class: one is a `__main__.BarClass` while the other is a `test.BarClass` instance.

That's why you get the two outputs 15 followed by 10: the main script `bar` has had its `switch` method called, but the test module `bar` has not been switched.

Circular imports aside, importing your main script into another module has its own level of badness.

Answer (score 0):

Are you instantiating an object in `pyconsole` in `main.py`? If you've got a class called `PyConsole` in `pyconsole`, give its `__init__` method a parameter that takes the list of game objects. That way your `pyConsole` object will have a reference to the objects.

Hope this helps. It seems like you've just misunderstood the way Python works with imported modules.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the submitted code is that the `get` method of the `BarClass` class returns a value of `None` because the body of the method contains only a print statement. Therefore, in `distancefrom00.py` the result of the function `calculate` is:

```
str + str + str + str + None + str
```

Hence, the `TypeError: cannot concatenate a 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`

You can solve this problem by returning a string from a call to `get`. For example,

```
def get(self):
    return "The BAZ is %s" % self.baz
```

Also, note that you have a circular import in your two files. `test.py` imports `distancefrom00.py`, and `distancefrom00.py` imports `test.py`. As Kylotan says cyclic dependences are bad